Can we construct a CPA-secure scheme using a PRG?
Proving CPA security using a PRG in place of a PRF
I was reading this question, and was wondering what will happen if the pseudorandom generator $G$ is not known publicly (only known to the sender and receiver, not any adversary)? is the scheme CPA-secure now?
I suppose it is, since it's akin to choosing a fixed key in a PRF?

One of the issues here is formalizing the notion of "publicly known PRG”. But I assume it also boils down to implementing a PRG with a secondary input, which has essentially PRF-like behavior or even only weak PRF since the nonce is random. Naturally, the PRG still needs to be secure, since public ignorance isn't enough for security.

"Secret algorithms" (1) fly in the face of best practices (Kerckhoffs' Principle) and (2) are difficult to formalize for the sake of provable security. A "secret PRG algorithm" is so different from a usual PRG that it becomes pointless to even describe it as a PRG.
